# Remove `www.` from QUrl in Qt 5.5

Tags: c++, qt, qurl

So in another part of my program I read out various urls from my browser.
Say I have `http://www.example.com` as well as `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`. For a browser, these three urls are different.
To me, only the 'base' domain (`example.com`) is important.

I now am trying to strip the `www` from the domain, however, can not succeed. I'd like to do so using the provided QUrl library instead of checking whether the string includes a `www.` and remove it afterwards.
As you can see, it's more of a design-decision here ;)

Here's my current application.

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QList>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QList<QUrl> urlList;
    urlList << QUrl("http://example.com/qwe/whoami/123#123141");

    urlList << QUrl("chrome://newtab/");
    urlList << QUrl("favorites://");
    urlList << QUrl("");

    urlList << QUrl("https://www.google.de/");
    urlList << QUrl("https://google.de/");
    urlList << QUrl("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTPGpBBqwe");

    urlList << QUrl("https://youtube.com/watch?v=189273ijadzqiuwejk");
    urlList << QUrl("http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/10371/whoisthisyo");
    urlList << QUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478464/alfresco-custom");

    urlList << QUrl("http://localhost:3000");
    urlList << QUrl("localhost:3000");

    for (int i = 0; i < urlList.count(); i++) {
        qDebug() << "[" << i+1 << "] " << urlList[i].host();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't bother, just use `QString.replace()` with `www` as oldvalue and `""` as the new one

Comment: Does that mean there's no elegant way to accomplish my described goal? ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function provided out of the box.

The best solution I can think of is to replace the `"www."` **at the beginning of the host part** of the URL, if it exists.

Note that you should not remove any other occurence of the string `"www."` in the host or even in the rest of the URL, so we check if the `QUrl::host()` begins with `"www."` and then remove those four characters from it.

Also note that technically, this changes the host name in a way it could lead you to a different web site. (Although practically, every website should deliver the same content with or without the `www.` subdomain prefix for usability reasons.) Also, it could lead to totally unintended results for some special cases, for example where `www.` is not even a subdomain: the domain `www.com` will result in just `com`.

```
QUrl remove_www(QUrl url) {
    QString host = url.host();
    if (host.startsWith("www."))
        host = host.mid(4); // = remove first 4 chars
    url.setHost(host);
    return url;
}
```

Then use the return value of this function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < urlList.count(); i++) {
    qDebug() << "[" << i+1 << "] " << remove_www(urlList[i]);
}
```